# SQL Server - Adding primary key to large database

Tags: php, mysql

I have database with 300 tables without primary key, currently i want to add add primary key to the table with auto increment value because i am not able to edit or delete any data through MYSQL PHPMYADMIN. I know its possible, but it consist of billions of data.

Is there any problem for adding new primary key to all tables those tables not having primary key currently?.

Is there any issues will effect to existing queries written previously?.

What is best way to do it without effecting any ongoing process in live server?.

Is it possible to edit or delete sql table rows without adding primary key in the live server without effecting ongoing process in live server?. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any problem for adding new primary key to all tables those tables not having
>
> Is there any issues will effect to existing queries written previously?.primary key currently?

You can add the PK. But if your queries are build like

```
SELECT *
```

Then you will have an extra column and that may broke your other systems.

> What is best way to do it without effecting any ongoing process in live server?.

You have to do it in a test server first.

> Is it possible to edit or delete sql table rows without adding primary key in the live server without effecting ongoing process in live server?

If you have some process running they may have table lock so the table updates cant happen. That is why you should schedule a downtime for maintenance where you can do the changes. And as I said before you have to plan and test everything on the test server first.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will checkout and reply.